# Why react `useRef` hook stores the objects in `current` property? Why cant it store directly in the ref object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Why does the object returned by the `useRef` hook stores whatever value it's supposed to hold in `current` property? Why can't we assign something directly into the ref object as shown below:

```
const sampleRef = useRef([]);

/** why can't we do this... */
sampleRef.push('1');

/** ...instead of this? Why an extra `current` object? */
sampleRef.current.pus('1');
```

What is the purpose of `useRef` returning the argument wrapped inside another object with `current` property?

Comment: One thing worth notice is that changing the value of the current property of an object IS storing directly in that object. So your question title kinda contradicts with itself.

Answer (score 8):

The answer to this question is not specific to React and its hooks system.
Mutating an object is just a solution to how you share values between different closures / scopes.

When you call `useRef()` for your component a "ref object" is created in React internals, tied to that particular instance of your component.
Each time `useRef()` is called across multiple renders, the same "ref object" is returned. Setting `current` on it is how your store a value to re-access it on next render.

By doing something like

```
let value = useRef();
value = 1234;
```

you're throwing away the ref object, replacing it with a new value in your local scope. There's no way React can track that action and update the ref object that is stored in its internals. (In fact React does not track any action to "ref objects" anyway, it just gives them to you. You mutate them, you access them).

But with the current API, you do

```
const ref = useRef(); // ref is an object that is stored somewhere in React internals
ref.current = 1234; // you update the property of that object
```

The next time your component renders, React gives you the same ref object, so that you can use the value that you set previously.

Comment: Worth mentioning that for `<div ref={ref} />` cases that's also the only way to pass `ref.current` instead of replacing elsewhere the `ref` pointer, as that's indeed not possible in JS.

Answer (score 2):

As I understood, they made it because they needed to create an object in order to seal the **DOM element object**(in development mode) and **memoize** it. As you know if we are going to memoize something, we need to convert it to an **object** or **array**.

Reference:

```js
function mountRef<T>(initialValue: T): {current: T} {
  const hook = mountWorkInProgressHook();
  const ref = {current: initialValue};
  if (__DEV__) {
    Object.seal(ref);
  }
  hook.memoizedState = ref;
  return ref;
}
```

https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.js#L916

Comment: "As you know if we are going to memoize something, we need to convert it to an object or array." - could you please explain why should I know that? It's not possible to memoize numbers or strings?

Comment: Yes, it should be possible to memorize every js types but as I know, two objects or array is not equal together. means {} === {} is false or [] === []. but 1 === 1 is true

Comment: That's because 1 is 1 but no object is the same object as another object. Pretty logical for me.

Answer (score 1):

The react hooks system works with immutable values. Whenever the component is rendered, the hooks are called (for example the `useState` hook), and they produce a value or two (state and setter function). If this values are changed from the previous values, other hooks might be called (`useEffect` when the setter function is initialised).

However, sometimes we don't want to react to this changes. We don't really care what is the value as long as it's there, and we don't care if something changes it. For this cases we've got the [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables):

> The “ref” object is a generic container whose current property is
>   mutable and can hold any value, similar to an instance property on a
>   class.

Whenever you need to store a value, that will be used, but won't cause a re-render, nor cause `useMemo`, `useCallback`, `useEffect`, etc... to recompute, you can set that value via a ref. Since the ref itself will be used as part of hooks dependencies (`useMemo(() => {}, [ref]`), you can't update it. To enable immutability, a property inside that `ref` object, can be changed `ref.current`, without causing the dependant to recompute, since it's the same ref.

Comment: _Since the ref itself will be used as part of hooks dependencies (useMemo(() => {}, [ref]),_. Did you mean as part of useRef's dependancy.?

Comment: Nope. The ref will be used by other hooks, for example useMemo or useEffect dependencies, and the idea is that after the 1st change (init of the ref), mutating the ref (changing current) won't cause the dependants to recompute - ie useMemo calling the function to generate the value again.

Comment: So what is different between useRef and useState or useReducer hence you said to enable immutability?

Comment: The difference is that changing a ref (the current) doesn't replace the entire ref.

Comment: "The react hooks system works with immutable values". Wait, what? `useRef()` is a hook. It does return a mutable object. `ref.current = "newValue"` is **mutating that object**.

Comment: The ref is the mutable escape hatch. The rest should be immutable. That's why you need ref in this scenario.

Comment: The most common use case of `useRef` is storing DOM elements and component instances in refs by adding `ref={ref}`. Should I remind that they are mutable?

Comment: _Since the ref itself will be used as part of hooks dependencies_
Why one should ever use a ref object as a hook dependency? I've always thought that the dependencies are used by React only to keep track of their changes. But since refs never change, it seems useless to add them to dependencies. Am I wrong?

Answer (score -1):

I'm trying to answer the root cause of your question, which I interpret to be something like: "It seems that we should not need an intermediate object with a .current property." You're correct. We don't. Whatever the actual reason regarding `useRef`, I have noticed it is possible to instead do something like the following, which has the kind of syntax you were asking for in your question (the elimination of `.current`). Please note this is an advanced usage that actually creates a component local cache like `useRef`, but that doesn't talk to the DOM.:

```
//note foo is in array brackets by itself
const [foo /*no setFoo here*/] = useState({bar:"baz"});
...
foo.bar="hello"
```

or

```
//note foo in brackets by itself
const [foo /*no setFoo here*/] = useState([]);
...
foo.push(1);
```

This lets us directly mutate `foo`'s properties without using `.current`. As long as we never call `setFoo`, mutating `foo`'s properties will not cause a rerender on its own. The value of `foo` itself is never changed, since it always points to the same object or array.

However, it is possible, just as with any other variables including `useRef` ones, to cause a `useEffect` hook to rerun after a rerender if a changed property like `foo.bar` appears in the 2nd argument array of the `useEffect`.

I haven't tried `let [foo]= useState("whatever")` yet. In that case, we'd be altering the actual value of `foo`, and depending on React to give that altered value back to us on subsequent rerenders, even though we never notified React of the change. Seems sketchy.